# Generate CRUD UI automatically in WPF through Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, scaffolding

I am new to WPF. I want to know if there any feature exists in WPF using which, we can generate auto UI for CRUD operation using entity framework as we do in Asp.Net MVC?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not such built-in feature in WPF. But you can use DataTemplates, ControlTemplates and User interface patterns such as MVVM and MVP to implement your own library to do that.